# which version to use to build bot: bot framework SDK 3.x or SDK4.0?

Tags: botframework, bots

Since I used to build bot using SDK 3.x, recently 4.0 is out. Though the documentation is very poor for bot framework SDK4., is it recommended to use for new bots?

does support for SDK 3.x stops in future?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Officially, v4 is now the stable and up-to-date version. From the official repository [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-V3/blob/master/README.md):

> If you are new to the Bot Builder SDK, we strongly encourage you to
>   build your bot using the v4 SDK.

v3 will still be supported for a while, but in the end this support will be stopped (I can't find the date).

You can have a look to the roadmap of v4 here: https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/wiki/Roadmap